# Preposizione per l'espressione venire in aiuto

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Mentre leggevo un testo da revisionare, mi è venuto un atroce dubbio: l'espressione "venire in aiuto" richiede la preposizione *di* oppure *a*?

Ad esempio si dice:

> il veliero venne in aiuto ***dei*** naufraghi

oppure

> il veliero venne in aiuto ***ai*** naufraghi?

A prima vista mi sembrano corrette entrambe, ma non sono in grado di dire quale sia la forma migliore, oppure se ci siano dei casi specifici in cui una o l'altra preposizione siano preferibili.

Ho cercato qua e là ma non ho trovato una risposta soddisfacente. Potete venire in mio aiuto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sembra  non  esserci una vera differenza nell’uso di *venire in aiuto a* vs *venire in aiuto di*.

[Google books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=venire%20in%20aiuto%20a%2Cvenire%20in%20aiuto%20di&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvenire%20in%20aiuto%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvenire%20in%20aiuto%20di%3B%2Cc0) mostra  l’uso di entrambe le preposizioni senza evidenziare una particolare prevalenza di una sull’altra.

Comment: Penso che la risposta possa migliorare includendo alcuni esempi letterari di "venire in aiuto di" e "venire in aiuto a". Sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* se ne trovano parecchi. Vedi http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Sequenza?q=in+aiuto, http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Sequenza?q=in+aiuto&page=2, 
http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Sequenza?q=in+aiuto&page=3, ecc.